# Delay between CSS background change

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to rotate CSS backgrounds by calling `setTimeout` on functions, however the code doesn't work as expected. There is only one transition, and then it skips to the last image right away.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2fr5o0q/)

```
var func = function () { 

    setTimeout( function(){
      $('#rotator').css("background-image", "url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/diamond_upholstery.png)"); 
    },2000);

    setTimeout( function(){
      $('#rotator').css("background-image", "url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/subtle_stripes.png)"); 
    },2000);

    setTimeout( function(){
      $('#rotator').css("background-image", "url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/struckaxiom.png)"); 
    },2000);

    setTimeout( function(){
      $('#rotator').css("background-image", "urlhttp://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/dark_stripes.png)"); 
    },2000);

    setTimeout(func, 0);

}
setTimeout(func, 0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`:

```js
var i = 0;
var rotator = document.querySelector('#rotator');
var path = 'http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/';

var backgrounds = [
'diamond_upholstery',
'subtle_stripes',
'struckaxiom',
'dark_stripes'
];

function func(i) {
setInterval(function(){
if (i === (backgrounds.length-1)) {i = 0;} else {i++;}
rotator.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + path + backgrounds[i] + '.png)';}, 2000);
}

window.onload = func(i);
```

```css
#rotator {
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
background-image:url('http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/diamond_upholstery.png');
}
```

```html
<div id="rotator">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do without a lot of the setTimeouts, try something like this:

```
var func = function () {
    var images = [
        'http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/diamond_upholstery.png',
        'http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/subtle_stripes.png',
        'http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/struckaxiom.png',
        'http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/dark_stripes.png'
    ]; 
    var state = $('#rotator').data('background-image-state');
    var newState = state % images.length;
    $('#rotator').data('background-image-state', newState);
    $('#rotator').css("background-image", "url("+images[newState]+")");

    setTimeout(func, 2000);

}
$('#rotator').data('background-image-state', 0);
setTimeout(func, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the duration of your timeouts to be different, right now they all end at the same time (2000ms).  If you want each to be 2000ms a part, make them `2000`, `4000`, `6000`, `8000`.

Comment: But doesn't 2000ms mean that it executes 2sec after the last statement has finished? I tried your solution, and it created some unintended consequences as time went on: http://jsfiddle.net/e2fr5o0q/1/

Comment: Hmm, so what is causing the issue in the effect becoming unstable over time? http://jsfiddle.net/e2fr5o0q/2/

Comment: @pufAmuf because timeouts lose sync: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/  This would fix it but...  http://jsfiddle.net/e2fr5o0q/3/  Better would be to set an infinite animation in CSS

Comment: I just answered why the initial delay didn't work.  According to your fiddle, now the first images have a delay.  The real problem is you are setting timeouts with no delay which is the cause for the strobing.

Comment: Ahh okay, I will keep that in mind next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use callback functions. Following is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zv3gjde3/) depicting the same.

#### Code

```js
function updateImage(url, callback) {
    var _url = 'http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/';
    _url += url;
    $('#rotator').css("background-image", "url(" + _url + ")");
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}

var func = function () {
    updateImage("diamond_upholstery.png",
    function () {
        updateImage("subtle_stripes.png",
        function () {
            updateImage("struckaxiom.png",
            function () {
             updateImage("dark_stripes.png",
                           function(){})
            });
        })
    });
}
setTimeout(func, 2000);
```

```css
#rotator {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/diagmonds.png);
    transition: background 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotator"></div>
```